# Lombok Annotations and inheritance

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I am currently developing a project in Spring boot and I am having some issues in inherited classes. The issues are coming from the fact that I use annotations in the abstract parent class (such as @Data) but these do not get inherited by the child classes. I am also using chatgpt to ask questions (since its my first spring boot project) and it mentions that "Lombok annotations are indeed inherited by child classes in Java, including Spring Boot projects. If a parent class has Lombok annotations like @Data, @AllArgsConstructor, @NoArgsConstructor, etc., the child class should inherit these annotations and their behavior without requiring redundant annotations in the child class." However, even inputing my classes into it does not seem to identify or help with the problem.

Here is an example of the classes:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class AbstractResponse {
    private boolean success;
}
```

followed by a child class:

```
public class QuoteResponse extends AbstractResponse{
    private double c;
    private double d;
    private double dp;
    private double h;
    private double l;
    private double o;
    private double pc;
    private long t;
}
```

If I don´t use @Data in the child class I don´t have getter and setters. Initially I though this was normal but since chatgpt mentioned several times it should work I want to clarify it.

Comment: Lombok's annotations do only take effect on the direct class they are placed on. In general, annotations are not inherited by default. Only when the annotation class itself is annotated with [`@Inherited` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) are they inherited.

Comment: Ok so if I want to inherit the annotations I need to annotate with @Inherited? Does it have any drawbacks or is it safe to use?

Comment: The Lombok annotations would need to be _meta annotated_ themselves with `@Inherited`. You cannot put `@Inherited` on your classes, only on annotations.

Comment: The annotation itself must be annotated. You cannot do that since you cannot modify the (official) lombok code. Aside from this, even if it were possible, I am not sure how the lombok annotation processor exactly works, i.e. if it would take effect. Maybe @rzwiterloot sees this post and cares to explain.

Comment: Ok it's clear, thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source of the Lombok annotations (for example [`AllArgsConstructor`](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/AllArgsConstructor.java#L41):

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface AllArgsConstructor {
```

or [`Data`](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/Data.java#L45):

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Data {
```

) you can see that those annotations are themselves annotated with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)`.

The [`RetentionPolicy.SOURCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#SOURCE) annotation means the generated class files doesn't contain any trace of the Lombok annotation any more:

> ```
> public static final RetentionPolicy SOURCE
> ```
>
> Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.